# Docker swarm propagate changes in container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, high-availability

I am fairly new to docker and docker swarm.

Recently I got a request from a business client that has 3 servers running cPanel/WHM with some wordpress installed on each server.

He wants to replicate each server 3 times for high availability, having a total of 9 nodes in the network.

My question is, what happens if, for example, one new post is added to one of the wordpress sites? How can I make that change to propagate to the other nodes that are replicas of the main one where the change was made?

My assumption is to deploy cPanel in a container having all data in volumes, use docker swarm to replicate it and finally use another software to sync files between containers. But I am sure that there should be a better, more professional and more straightforward approach to this.

Can anyone advice me?

Thanks